# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined - in jqGrid Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, jqgrid

I got the message : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in jqGrid.min.js . When I submit to update data from grid.

my script:

```
$('#list-student').jqGrid({
    url: 'GetAllStudent',
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames:['ID','Student', 'Birth day', 'Is Male ?','Province'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', editable:false,width:100, align:'center'},
        {name:'name',index:'name',editable:true, width:240},
        {
            name:'birth',
            index:'birth',
            editable:true,
            width:200,
            align:'center',
            editoptions:{
                size:12,
                dataInit:function(el){
                    $(el).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
                        beforeShow: function(){
                            $('.ui-datepicker').css({'font-size': 11, 'line-height': 1.2})
                            }   
                    });
                }
            },
            editrules:{required:true}
        },
        {name:'male',index:'male', editable:true, formatter:'checkbox',width:100, align:'center',edittype:'checkbox',editoptions:{value:'true:false'}},
        {name:'homeTown.nameProvince',editable:true, index:'province', align:'center',edittype:'select',editoptions:{dataUrl:'GetAllProvinceHTML'}}     
    ],
    jsonReader : {repeatitems:false},
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#pager',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    loadonce: true,
    caption:'List Students',
    editurl: 'EditStudent'
});

$('#list-student').jqGrid(
    'navGrid',
    '#pager',
    {view:true},
    {
        reloadAfterSubmit:false, 
        closeOnEscape:true,
        jqModal:true,
        afterSubmit:function(response, post_data){
            console.log(response.responseText);
        },
        closeAfterEdit: true
    }, // edit options
    {reloadAfterSubmit:false,jqModal:true, closeOnEscape:true,bottominfo:'Fields marked with (*) are required', closeAfterAdd: true}, // add options
    {reloadAfterSubmit:false,jqModal:true, closeOnEscape:true}, // del options
    {closeOnEscape:true}, // search options
    {jqModal:true,closeOnEscape:true} // view options       
);
```

in Spring Controller

```
package controller;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import model.Province;
import model.ProvinceService;
import model.Student;
import model.StudentService;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="PostMes", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public class StudentController {
    @RequestMapping(value="Get",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String abc(){
        return "Manage";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="GetAllStudent",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Student> getAllStudent(){
        StudentService sts=new StudentService();
        List<Student> list= sts.getAllStudents();
        return list;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="GetAllProvince",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Province> getAllProvince(){
        ProvinceService sts=new ProvinceService();
        List<Province> list= sts.getAllProvinces();
        return list;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "GetAllProvinceHTML", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html;charset=UTF-8")
    public  @ResponseBody String getAllProcinveHTML(HttpServletResponse response){
        ProvinceService sts=new ProvinceService();
        List<Province> list= sts.getAllProvinces();
        String returnString="";
        for(Province pro:list){
            returnString+="<option id='"+pro.getId()+"'>"+pro.getNameProvince()+"</option>";    
        }
        returnString="<select class='provinceGroup'>" + returnString + "</select>"; 
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return returnString;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "EditStudent",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody List<Student> editStudent(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res){
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("id"));
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("oper"));//what operation we re doing example: "add" , "edit"
        System.out.println("Controller recieved");
        List<String> returnList=new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Student> list=new ArrayList<Student>();
        Student st=new Student();
        st.setName("Shayne");
        list.add(st);
        list.add(st);list.add(st);list.add(st);list.add(st);
        return list;
    }
}
```

When I edit a row, and click submit => in controller received request , but after sent response to client I got message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in jqGrid.min.js"

my include :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jqGrid/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jqGrid/jqGrid.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use? Could you repeat the test with `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and include the line number of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` where the error take place?

Comment: @Oleg I replaced by jqGrid.src.js and still have this error in line 7936:

jqGrid.src.js:7936 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: I repeat my previous question: **Which version of jqGrid you use?**. Neither jqGrid 4.7 nor 4.6 have suspected lines in the line 7936.

Comment: srr, I forgot give the version! My jqGrid version 4.7

Comment: @Oleg : I found solution for this issue, I removed 

afterSubmit:function(response, post_data){                            console.log(response.responseText);

and it's working fine! Can you explain for me please ?

Comment: Sorry, but the line 7936 of jqGrid 4.7 contains only `}`. It can't produce the error "Cannot read property '0' of undefined". So I do suppose that you use another version of jqGrid or the error was in another line. About `afterSubmit`. You can just add any callback in the grid with `console.log` or something like that. You have to hold the rules of *the callback*. For example `afterSubmit` should return array with 1 till 3 items. In case of no error detected you should use `return [true];` from `afterSubmit`.

Comment: About the error "Cannot read property '0' of undefined". I do remind about such error in some old version of jqGrid. The reason was `dataInit` callback was called *multiple times* and one time it will be called erroneously with `el` as absolutely wrong parameter. It was fixed by me by adding `dataInit` in `setAttributes` (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.common.js#L312)) if I remind correctly the problem.

Comment: @Oleg : thanks for your help. all are working fine ^^

Answer (score 0):

the afterSubmit must return an array for instance :

```
afterSubmit: function()(response, postdata) {
   var res = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
   if(YOUR_CONDITION_NOT_SATISFIED) {
        return [false,'MY ERROR MESSAGE'];
    }
    else {
        return [true];
    }
}
```